# How to make a delay between printing characters in a string print loop?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print each character separately and have a delay between them, so when I run the loop, instead of each character printing immediately it prints one character at a time.

The goal is to have a string that would be printed out one letter at a time and it would look like it is being typed out by the program.

I used a code for the delay that I found on the internet at it is supposed to make a time delay between the printing of the characters.

```
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <time.h>    
#include <string.h>    

void delay(unsigned int milliseconds) {    
    clock_t start = clock();    
    while ((clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < milliseconds);    
}    

int main() {    
    int c = 0;    
    char s[6] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };    
    for (c = 0; s[c] != '\0'; c++) {    
        printf("%c", s[c]);    
        delay(1000);    
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

I expected for it to be printed every letter at a time with a second delay between each letter, but instead it waits 6 seconds and prints everything out.

Comment: This technique is called busy wait, it is unnecessarily crude and cpu intensive, causing battery drain. You should use `sleep(1)` instead, which suspends the thread efficiently. Adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` will solve the incremental issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Output from `printf` and other functions that write to `stdout` and other files may be buffered, so they may appear to print only when the buffer is flushed.

You can add the line `fflush(stdout)` inside your loop to force the buffer to be flushed to the stream, guaranteeing that any pending output currently in the buffer will be written out.

Comment: @TheSnoze to indicate that an answer has solved your problem, you may mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox icon near the voting arrows

Comment: @GovindParmar: *inside your loop* is ambiguous... before the call to `delay(1000)` would be better, posting a modified version of the code would be best.